# Show custom message when attempting to use the same phone for Account?

Tags: apex, workflow, validation-rule

I am new to the `Salesforce` OOB features as of now. I have an `Account` and made the Phone field compulsory while creating an account.

Ex: I have an Account created using `Phone=(911) 345-0987`, if someone tried to create the account using the same phone, then he should get the error message saying that `Phone=(911) 345-0987` is already in used. Please use the other one.

How to achieve this functionality ?

**Note: If I used trigger solution, then it works only for the 50,000 Accounts and after that it will not works???**

**Update-1, posts Santanu's answer:**

[image]

Comment: You need to probably use a trigger to check for duplicates

Comment: @Carlos Naranjo - Please see my answers below and few doubts along with that ?

Comment: @Carlos Naranjo - Will this works for bulk data upload ?

Comment: I think, you have taken the picture when duplicate rule settings is "allow" options and it will show alert or report, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rather than using trigger, it is recommended to leverage OOTB Duplicate Management.
>
> **Define Matching Rules**

[image: matching rule]

> **Define Duplicate Rule (Allow, display alert and report)**

[image: duplicate rule]

> **Display of error during duplicate record creation**

[image: duplicate error]

> **Define Duplicate Rule (block)**

[image: define rule block]

> **Display of error during duplicate record creation**

[image: block error]

For more information, refer [Managing Duplicate Records
in Salesforce](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_quality_duplicate_prevention.pdf)

or [Duplicate Management Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management)

Also, think of making the Phone field as unique in the configuration, just in case your use case supports, then this duplicate management will not be required.

Comment: Thanks. Only problem I see although it gives alert and if still go for it then it saves the same account for both Number. What we can do in this regard? Pls see above posts updates and answer on all query.

Comment: updated my answer, you can configure to entirely block. So no duplicated reocrds get saved

Comment: I like this approach, its clean. Also better to go for this instead of Trigger I think.

Comment: Can we deploy Matching Management using Change Set ?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy that

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the very standard trigger used for Leads which it is a old SFDC example on how to use trigger:

```
trigger accountPhonePreventer on Account (before insert, before update) {

Map<String, Account> accountMap = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account account : System.Trigger.new) {

    if ((account.Phone != null) &&
            (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
            (account.Phone != 
                System.Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id).Phone))) {

        if (accountMap.containsKey(account.Phone)) {
            account.Phone.addError('Another new account has the '
                                + 'same phone number.');
        } else {
            accountMap.put(account.Phone, account);
        }
   }
}

for (Account account : [SELECT Phone FROM Account
                  WHERE Phone IN :accountMap.KeySet()]) {
    Account newAccount = accountMap.get(account.Phone);
    newAccount.Phone.addError('A account with this phone number '
                           + 'already exists.');
  }
}
```

This should prevent the inserting and update of accounts with the same phone and it will display the error on `addError`

This error should fire every time that an account meets the criteria, in this case, same phone number.

I will also suggest that you move your code logic out of your triggers. 
You can create help class with your logic and then call it from your trigger.

Comment: Can we override SDFC custom message ? I have already highlighted in bold in my post above !

Answer (score -1):

Thanx @Carlos Naranjo for suggestions. I write trigger which shows me my custom error message.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    for(Account acct : Trigger.New){
        List<Account> acctList = [Select Id, AccountNumber from Account where Phone= :acct.Phone];
        if(acctList.size() > 0){
            acct.addError('Phone '+acct.Phone +' is already present. Please use other one.');
        }
    }
}
```

**I don't want to show error message highlighted in the green box. Does this using trigger solution will work for only 50,000 accounts only ? What after 50,000 accounts ?**

[image]

Comment: Your solution won't work if there are duplicate records in the file itself.